# Should I be developing Android apps with Xamarin instead of Java?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

I want to make a project for the summer where I want to create an Android app. Now my question is for those who have used Xamarin before to create Android apps:

- Is it better to create Android apps with Java than in C# with Xamarin?
- Are there any restrictions with usin Xamarin for Android app development?
  I.e. are there some things that I can do in Java but not in Xamarin?
- And last, what do you think about Xamarin for a pretty new programmer?

Comment: I've heard from friends that programming with java gives better performance. I haven't tried it out so I can't confirm or deny that but you can look into that.
The restrictions depend on if you want to spend money on buying a license from Xamarin.
You can use the framework for free but you can only write programs that are relatively small. I believe its 30 or 70kb. Besides that you can't use third party libraries with the free version. A license will cost about 300 dollars.
For the last question: I love programming with Xamarin for Android. I find it much simpler to do.

Answer (score 3):

You specifically asked to:

> create an android app

If that is your only requirement, and you have no previous experience in C# development, you should stick to developing the application using JAVA and Android SDKs. After all, it is free of charge.

However,
Why do you want to limit yourself to Android platforms?

If there is a chance that you might want to expand to other platforms in the future, you should IMHO start preparing for it right now, and create a cross-platform application.

C# is a powerful language, Xamarin products are mature and of high quality and Xamarin community is big enough for wide support.
There are no restrictions that I know of, and everything that you can do with native Java you can also achieve with Xamarin.Android. Also, in case you will ever find any restriction, you can always include [Native Java Code](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview) inside your application.

The only thing to mind is the price, which is probably high for a beginner developer.

Comment: If it was helpful, you can always mark it as answer to show your appreciation... :)

Comment: @Liel Actually there **are** some restrictions in Xamarin. Well, kind of. Xamarin is done by porting the framework to C#. That haven't ported everything, so there are very few things that you can do in Java but not in Xamarin. This is pretty negligible and they are trying to add more with every version, but I just wanted to mention it for the sake of correctness.

Comment: @Liel As an example of the incremental porting, you can [see this link](http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Missing-overload-of-Html-FromHtml-td5619234.html). One of the overloads of `Html.FromHtml()` function was not implemented back then. That was back in 2012, and I haven't checked if they've added it sine, but this just gives the idea. In most cases you can implement the missing library by yourself, but that could be a lot of work for some features. So although theoretically you can do everything that you can do in Java, but practically some very few features can be harder.

Answer (score 1):

An additional feature which is in C# but is omitted in Java is LINQ which gives significant assistance to data handing and sorting.

The main factor to consider is as Liel has already said your preference of programming Language, Java or C#, go with which you are more comfortable with. The only hesitation which I would mention when referring someone to Xamarin as opposed to Java is that their is significantly tutorials out their.

This in my view though should become less of an issue in time. The main source which I use when I am learning is AppDev and Pluralsight Training DVDs and have found them to be essential in learning.

It is possible to simply refer to Java sources the only manipulation sometimes needed is to capitalize the first character setContentView() => SetContentView() in C#, and then using Intelisence to find the correct syntax Resource instead of R in Java.

Good luck with whatever you choose,
James